# IntelliJ IDEA 2016 JAR run config: use variable version number

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar

I have a jar built with maven, such that the version number included in the name, for example `thing-1.0.0.jar`.

In IntelliJ 2016, I'm then using a JAR run configuration to run the jar. My run configuration is set up like this:

[image]

The problem is that the `Path to JAR` config points to the exact filename, so every time I bump the version number, and the built jar filename changes, say `thing-1.0.0.jar` > `thing-1.0.1.jar`, I have to manually update the run configuration too, to run the newer version.

What I'd like to do instead:

**ideally**

Put the current version number in using some kind of variable, where the value would be retrieved from the project's pom. This would obviously be a specialised IntelliJ feature, and I'm not sure this exists.

**or, good enough**

Just match any version number with a regex, since just running whatever the latest built version happens to be solves my problem in practice. I've played around trying to do this in the `Path to JAR` field, but it just reads my regex as a literal value - if this is indeed a feature, I can't find the right syntax for using it.

**So, are either of these solutions possible? Or is there another, better way to achieve this goal with IntelliJ 2016 run configurations?** I've googled this in every phrasing I can think of and and have looked at [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-jar-application.html) and can't find anything.

*Note: I know I could use a maven plugin to handle the running, but I'd prefer to avoid an extra dependency. I want to do this with the integrated IntelliJ tooling, if possible.*

Comment: is it acceptable to call the jar-file via cmd-script? In this script, you can use a maven property which is replaced with the version number during build process.

Comment: @Ulrich thanks, I'll look at this